Error en el manejo de booleanos para ejecutar la biblioteca sweetviz de python
muy buen día
Estoy intentando ejecutar lo siguiente para generar un reporte con sweetviz donde me segmente el análisis entre género masculino y femenino, cabe mencionar que en mi DataFrame la columna es 'gender' y los datos de genero los tengo como 'm'y 'f' e intento convertirlos en booleanos para poder ejecutar la biblioteca , no tengo datos faltantes ni espacio en blanco , entonces el codigo que estoy intentando ejecutar y que me genera un error es este

import pandas as pd
import sweetviz as sv

# Verifica los valores de 'gender' para asegurarnos que esté en formato correcto
print(promotion['gender'].value_counts())

# Convertir la columna 'gender' en una serie booleana
promotion['gender_bool'] = promotion['gender'] == 'm'  # True si 'm', False si 'f'

# Crear el reporte usando 'gender_bool' como la columna de comparación
report = sv.compare_intra(
    promotion,  # DataFrame completo
    target_feat='gender_bool',  # Columna que queremos comparar
    condition_series=promotion['gender_bool'],  # Condición para 'Masculino'
    names=['Masculino', 'Femenino']  # Etiquetas para los dos grupos
)

# Mostrar el reporte en el notebook
report.show_html('/content/reporte_gender_comparativo.html')

# Descargar el archivo generado
from google.colab import files
files.download('/content/reporte_gender_comparativo.html')

print("El reporte se ha generado y guardado como 'reporte_gender_comparativo.html'.")



Sin embargo, el código genera el siguiente error:

gender
m    38496
f    16312
Name: count, dtype: int64
Feature: gender_bool (TARGET)                
 [  6%]   00:00 -> (00:02 left)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key)
   3790         try:
-> 3791             return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3792         except KeyError as err:

index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.UInt8HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.UInt8HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 1

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
12 frames
KeyError: True

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in convert_missing_indexer(indexer)
   2605 
   2606         if isinstance(indexer, bool):
-> 2607             raise KeyError("cannot use a single bool to index into setitem")
   2608         return indexer, True
   2609 

KeyError: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'


Agradecería enormemente si alguién supiera como ayudarme con la resolución de este problema, muchas gracias

Por que tratas de usar valores booleanos, en vez de solamente categorizar con m o f ??

@Excorpion Que tal muy buena noche, si justo en la prueba que estoy realizando, para resolver estos ejercicios, me lo están pidiendo, por lo que estoy viendo el argumento "compare_intra() requires condition_series to be boolean length"

No es necesario convertir gender a booleano, puedes usar la columna directamente. m y f ya son columnas categoricas, puedes comprar por una u la otra, y en caso de haber algún error, controlarlo.
report = sv.compare_intra(
    promotion,  # DataFrame completo
    target_feat='gender',  # Columna que queremos comparar
    condition_series=promotion['gender'],  # Condicion
    names=['Masculino', 'Femenino']  # Etiquetas para los dos grupos
)

Acá abajo, te dejaré la manera de validar que los valores sean los esperados y así controlar posibles errores.
if 'gender' not in promotion.columns:
    raise ValueError("La columna 'gender' no está presente en el DataFrame.")

valid_values = ['m', 'f'] # Valores validos para gender
unique_values = promotion['gender'].unique() # Obtener los valores unicos
if not all(value in valid_values for value in unique_values):
    raise ValueError("La columna 'gender' contiene valores inválidos")

if promotion['gender'].isnull().sum() > 0:
    raise ValueError("La columna 'gender' contiene valores nulos.")

if (promotion['gender'].str.strip() == "").any():
    raise ValueError("La columna 'gender' contiene valores vacíos o espacios en blanco.")


Muchas gracias por el apoyo y el tiempo estimado, si mira, acabo de integrar el código que me compartiste en mi notebook, sin embargo, el keyerror que me está generando es este: "KeyError:compare_intra() requires condition_series to be boolean length" , basicamente la condición compare.intra() sólo trabaja con datos booleanos (adicional a que me lo están pidiendo)
